# .htaccess dynamic subdomain files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

here is my code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /user/profile.php?name=%1 [L]
```

here is what it does:

if i visit `test.domain.com`, it will show the contents (not redirect) of `domain.com/profile.php?name=test`.

---

but if i type: `test.domain.com/login`, it will show the contents of the page: `domain.com/login`.

Question: **why is that? how can i turn that off?** thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work, working fine on my end.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.in
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.dmmain\.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://test.domain.in/user/profile.php [L,QSA]
```